# Returns a 'NoneType'? I enter literally any number and I just get 'None'. Why does this happen?

Tags: python

This specific chunk returns 'None' regardless of what number I enter.

```
max_pizzas = 5
min_pizzas = 1

def get_number_of_pizzas():
  while True:
    try:
       number_of_pizzas = int(input("How many pizzas would you like?"))
       break
    except ValueError:
      print("Please enter a valid number.")
    while number_of_pizzas > max_pizzas:
      print("We cannot deliver more than {} pizzas." .format(max_pizzas))
      break
    while number_of_pizzas < min_pizzas:
      print("Why are you here if you're not going to order?")
      break
    return number_of_pizzas
    
number_of_pizzas = get_number_of_pizzas()
print(number_of_pizzas)
```

Comment: Use an indent of 4 spaces; it makes it easier to separate levels of indentation, making an error like this more apparent.

Comment: You want `if` statements, not nested `while` loops, to check if the number of pizzas is too large or too small.

Comment: Might also be worth checking out... there's a fairly comprehensive post written there to try to explain these kind of things... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think clearly about the intended logic of the code. In your own words, what do you expect `break` to do? Where should `return number_of_pizzas` appear - inside the loop, or outside? Why?

Answer (score 4):

Your `return` statement is within the loop. When you `break` the loop, there is an implicit `return None` from the function, skipping over all code left within the loop body.

Rather than `break` on *valid* input, just `return number_of_pizzas` immediately, assuming it is valid with your other conditions. I.e. you should use `if` statements for the min/max checks, not while loops.

You use `continue` to go back to the start of the loop.

e.g.

```
def get_number_of_pizzas():
  while True:
    try:
       number_of_pizzas = int(input("How many pizzas would you like?"))
       if number_of_pizzas > max_pizzas:
           print("We cannot deliver more than {} pizzas." .format(max_pizzas))
           continue
       elif number_of_pizzas < min_pizzas:
           print("Why are you here if you're not going to order?")
           continue
       return number_of_pizzas
    except ValueError:
      print("Please enter a valid number.")
```